# New lines are not WYSIWYG

Tags: quill

In the editor, the Enter key has the following visual effect:

[image]

Hitting the Enter key once in the Quill editor results in `<p>...</p>` in `quill.root.innerHTML`.

With two consecutive Enter's, the output is now `<p><br/></p>`.

This resultant HTML from the above entered text would become:

[image]

This is quite different from how it looks when in the editor. How do people out there manage this? Do you have to massage `quill.root.innerHTML` or do you use some other method to display the entered content?

Comment: It'd be nice if you would edit your title be some concise version of the question that you are asking, E.g., "How to display line breaks entered in Quill" or some such.

Comment: This sounds like something you should report to the developers as a bug..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following style:

```
p { margin-bottom: 0 }
```

will produce the almost same look as in the editor.